# CSS3 Animations, not quite getting it right

Tags: html, css, animation

You can see what i have tried to do. But I want the bottom of each image rollover to appear after the right pops up and fades in. Not just when the mouse is hovered over the bottom of each image.

I'm also having trouble making the whole thing clickable to a blog post without overshadowing/stopping the individual links, and short code selection from being workable.

I've been at this for days with no luck... (The social icons, will be individual links but I've not done that yet)

Anyone see where I'm going wrong? I've got a fiddle at bottom. Ideally I'd like for it to all play on hover but obviously delay the black box at the bottom. I'm so close its annoyingly annoying.

HTML:

```
<body>
    <div class="wrapper">

            <div class="container left">
                <img src="http://www.glennleader.co.uk/wp-content/uploads/2014/05/suit6.jpg" alt="image" />
                <div class="sig"></div>
                <div class="innercontent css3-2">
                        <span class="css3-2 resize"><br/><h2><a href="bloglink">Title of the blog Post</a></h2>
                        <p>April 29, 2014</p>
                        <p><img src="http://www.glennleader.co.uk/wp-content/uploads/2014/05/share-buttons1-e1399999305264.png" /></p>
<p class="url"><textarea spellcheck="false">http://shortcodegoeshere.com/334</textarea></p>
<p><a href="link1">3/4 length</a> • <a href="link2">Agnelli check</a> • <a href="link3">bespoke jacket</a> • <a href="link4">Jacket</a> • <a href="link5">London Lounge</a></p><span class="clickhere"><a href="bloglink">Click here to read this article</a></span></span>



                </div>

            </div><!-- .container -->


        <div class="container right">
                <img src="http://www.glennleader.co.uk/wp-content/uploads/2014/05/suittemp.jpg" alt="image" />
                <div class="sig"></div>
                <div class="innercontent css3-2">
                        <span class="css3-2 resize"><br/><h2><a href="bloglink">Title of the blog Post</a></h2>
                        <p>April 29, 2014</p>
                        <p><img src="http://www.glennleader.co.uk/wp-content/uploads/2014/05/share-buttons1-e1399999305264.png" /></p>
<p class="url"><textarea spellcheck="false">http://shortcodegoeshere.com/334</textarea></p>
<p><a href="link1">3/4 length</a> • <a href="link2">Agnelli check</a> • <a href="link3">bespoke jacket</a> • <a href="link4">Jacket</a> • <a href="link5">London Lounge</a></p><span class="clickhere"><a href="bloglink">Click here to read this article</a></<span></span>



                </div>

            </div><!-- .container -->

        </footer>

    </div><!-- .wrapper -->


</body>
```

CSS:

```
    *{margin:0;padding:0;}

img {margin:0;padding:0px;}

.wrapper{
    margin:0 auto;
    width:720px;
    padding:30px;
    position:relative;
}

.left {float:left;}

.right {float:right;}

p {
    color:#000;
    font-size:14px;
    margin-bottom: 12px;
}

a{
    text-decoration:none;
    color: #000
}

h2, h2 a { font-size: 20px;
color: #000;
line-height: 30px;
}

h2 a:hover, a:hover {
 color:#F3625F;
}

.container{
    position:relative;
    overflow:hidden;
    width: 300px;
    max-height: 100%;
}

.sig {
    display: block;
    width: 98%;
    height: 98%;
    background: url(http://www.glennleader.co.uk/wp-content/uploads/2014/05/signature.png) bottom right no-repeat ;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    position:absolute;
    overflow: hidden;
}

.resize {
    width: 95%;
    height: 100%;
    position: absolute;
    display: block;
    overflow: hidden;
    padding: 0 2.5%;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    -webkit-transition: all .2s ease-out;
     -moz-transition: all .2s ease-out;
     transition: all .2s ease-out;
     opacity: 0;
}

   .resize:hover {
    opacity: 1;
}

.clickhere {
    position: absolute;
    display: block;
    overflow: hidden;
    width: 300px;
    height: 20px;
    padding: 15px 0;
    text-align: center;
    bottom: 0;
    left: 0;
    background: #000;
    opacity: 0;
    -webkit-transition: all .3s ease-in;
     -moz-transition: all .3s ease-in;
     transition: all .3s ease-in;
     animation-delay:2s;
    -webkit-animation-delay:2s;
    -moz-animation-delay:2s;

}
.clickhere:hover a {
    display: block;
    color: #fff;
    font-weight: 800;
}

.clickhere:hover {
    opacity: 0.5;
    cursor: pointer;
}

.clickhere a:hover {
 color:#F3625F
}

.url textarea {
width: 100%;
border: 0 none transparent;
margin: 0;
padding: 0;
outline: 0;
resize: none;
overflow: hidden;
font-family: inherit;
background: 0;
text-align: center;
font-size: 12px;
height: 16px;
-webkit-appearance: textarea;
-webkit-rtl-ordering: logical;
-webkit-user-select: text;
flex-direction: column;
cursor: auto;
white-space: pre-wrap;
word-wrap: break-word;
letter-spacing: normal;
word-spacing: normal;
text-transform: none;
text-indent: 0px;
text-shadow: none;
display: inline-block;
-webkit-writing-mode: horizontal-tb;
background: transparent;
}

.innercontent {
 display: block;
  height: 100%;
  text-align: center;
  width:100%;
  background:rgba(255,255,255,0.7);
   position:absolute;
}
.css3-2:hover .resize {

}

.css3-2 {
 bottom:-370px;left:0;
 -webkit-transition: all .5s ease-out;
 -moz-transition: all .5s ease-out;
 -o-transition: all .5s ease-out;
 transition: all .5s ease-out;
}

.innercontent a.css3-2{
 -webkit-transition: all .5s ease-out;
 -moz-transition: all .5s ease-out;
 -o-transition: all .5s ease-out;
 transition: all .5s ease-out;
}

.container:hover .css3-2 {
 bottom:4px;
 cursor: pointer;
}
```

Fiddle:

http://jsfiddle.net/Veriix/euXGZ/

Comment: (OT) `</a></<span>` is wrong HTML, probably a typo, but you should than use a better editor that highlights such stupid errors

Comment: (OT) also you have `</footer>` ... but where is `<footer>` ?

Comment: (OT) `<a href="bloglink">` what href is that?

Comment: Also avoid `SPAN` hold DIV or other Block Level elements. **Here's your updated fiddle**: http://jsfiddle.net/euXGZ/6/

Comment: http://www.whatwg.org/specs/web-apps/current-work/multipage/elements.html#phrasing-content

Answer (score 0):

The first issue is solved easy... you need to add the ::hover-pseudo class to the parent element to change the styles properly.

```
.css3-2:hover .clickhere a, .clickhere:hover a {
display: block;
color: #fff;
    font-weight: 800;
}

.css3-2:hover .clickhere, .clickhere:hover {
    opacity: 0.5;
    cursor: pointer;
}

 .css3-2 .clickhere a:hover, .clickhere a:hover {
 color:#F3625F

}
```

**Updated Fiddle:
http://jsfiddle.net/euXGZ/5/**

(I did not make any animation changes, just an update on the issue of displaying the link onhover)

EDIT: If you don't want the clickable element to slide in, give it an absolute positioning and maybe add some different animation (including a delay if you want it to wait til the slide in is done!)

```
animation-delay:2s;
-webkit-animation-delay:2s; /* Safari and Chrome */
```

---

https://www.facebook.com/j.beargraphics